# No inline_spacing in contour plot within matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, inline, contour, subplot

I'm using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots to create a 3x3 plot b/c it shares the axes easily. I then plot in each subplot a contourf and contour plot. When placing text in the contour plot, the inline_spacing is only correct in the last plot, otherwise there is no inline_spacing. It's as if I didn't turn on inline text for the first 8 subplots. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rfFile, rfMath, rfGeneral
plt.ion()

de_1 = list(np.linspace(0,100,101))
de_2 = list(np.linspace(0,100,101))
gain_2 = np.linspace(0,16,9)
levels = np.linspace(0,100,11)

de = np.array([[x,y] for x in de_1 for y in de_2])
dx = de[:,0]
dy = de[:,1]
xytri = rfGeneral.createTriMesh(dx, dy, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = ax.flatten()
for ix, g in enumerate(gain_2):
    print g
    de_tot = [(x*y)/(x + y/rfMath.db2lin(g)) for x in de_1 for y in de_2]
    de_tot = np.nan_to_num(de_tot)
    cs = ax[ix].tricontourf(xytri, de_tot, levels)
    ax[ix].set_title('Gain: {:2.0f} dB'.format(g))
    cs1 = ax[ix].tricontour(xytri, de_tot, levels, linewidths=1.5, colors='k')
    ax[ix].clabel(cs1, fmt = '%2.0f', fontsize=14, inline=1)

ax[0].set_ylim(min(de_2),max(de_2))
ax[0].set_xlim(min(de_1),max(de_1))
cax = plt.axes([0.93, 0.1, 0.025, 0.8])
fig.colorbar(cs, cax=cax)
ax[7].set_xlabel(r'$\eta_{D1}\,[\%]$',fontdict={'fontsize':20})
ax[3].set_ylabel(r'$\eta_{D2}\,[\%]$',fontdict={'fontsize':20})
fig.suptitle('Total Drain Efficiency', fontsize=24)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, left=0.075, right=0.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted a simple example which allows people to instantly replicate the issue. The rf* modules (what are they?) make it impossible for others to run your code, and only obfuscate the cause of the problem.

That said, setting `sharex` and `sharey` to `False` will probably resolve your issue. You can set the x and y limits manually based on the data.

I'm not sure what causes the issue. Perhaps sharing the axes applies some sort of transform to the clip_path which only makes it valid for the last axes. It looks like a bug to me.

#### With shared axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.025), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.025))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8,4), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                        subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)

for ax in axs.flat:
    cs = ax.contour(X, Y, X+Y)
    ax.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

[image]

#### Without shared axes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.025), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.025))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(8,4), sharex=False, sharey=False,
                        subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05, wspace=0.05)

for ax in axs.flat:
    cs = ax.contour(X, Y, X+Y)
    ax.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=10)
```

[image]